# Cannot get json/text in nodejs when url contains weird unicode characters

Tags: node.js, unicode

so I've been using the get-json module for getting json from a remote url. But every time I give it a url with weird unicode characters, it fails and gives an error. I have tried many other modules, but they all fail as well. What can i use to get text/json from a remote url when the url contains a weird unicode character?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the unicode characters to [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)

For example ☁.ws once converted is https://xn--l3hz130o.ws